# freeze jqgrid with editcell enable

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid where cellEdit is enabled. I want to freeze first two columns. can anyone please help me with this ? 
here is my code.

```
jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid({

        //url:"${context}/listOptys.do",
        datatype: "json",
        //mtype:"POST",

        height: '100%',
        width: 935,
        //autoWidth:true,
        colNames:['','','',' Name', ' Number', 'Volume','Probability', 'Date',  'Status'], 
        colModel:[ 
        {name:'Sk',index:'Sk', hidden:true,frozen:true},
        {name:'pkId',index:'pkId', hidden:true,frozen:true},
        {name:'projectsk',index:'projectsk', hidden:true,frozen:true},
        {name:'opportunityName',index:'opportunityName', width:240, align:"left", sortable:false,frozen:true}, 
        {name:'number',index:'number', width:70, align:"center", sortable:false},
        {name:'volume',index:'volume', width:70, align:"center", sortable:false},
        {name:'probablity',index:'probablity', width:70, align:"center", sortable:false},
        {name:'date',index:'date', width:70, align:"center", sortable:false},
        {name:'status',index:'status', width:70, align:"center", sortable:false}
        ]
        viewrecords: false,

        altRows: true,
        cellEdit:true,
        multiselect:true, 
        shrinkToFit:false
});
jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");
```

Thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 0):

Editing of jqGrid with frozen column is not possible in jqGrid 4.7, but I implemented the feature in free jqGrid which you can download from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). You can read more about the features of free jqGrid in [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki). For example [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit) you can find URLs which you can use to test free jqGrid directly from GitHub without any downloads.